# Array problems - Source not found

Tags: android, arrays, minesweeper

Hey guys I have got following problem:

I am just trying to create a new array with this code.

```
public class MineField {

Mine[][] mines;

public MineField(int cols, int rows) {
    mines = new Mine[cols][rows];
}
}
```

So when executing this code everything runs just fine of course. But when I just add a single line:

```
mines[0][0].setCoordinates(0,0);
```

The debug perspective opens and gives me some "ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line 2180

And some text in red
"Source not found"

I am working on an android application.

But I am not able to find out why I can't call a method of an object out of a freshly created object array?
I am trying to create a 2 dimensional array of mines and giving every single mine some specific coordinates.

Do You know some solutions or alternatives, then let me know!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You are most probably getting `NullPointerException` just because `mines[0][0]` is null
You should initialize Mine.

i.e

```
mines[0][0]=new Mine();
```

And then

```
mines[0][0].setCoordinates(0,0);
```

Comment: I very appreciate Your quick answer! So I assume that I have got to initialize every single object... Thanks!